# How to handle traffic spike without impacting database performance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I came across this question during my AWS study and am not with the provided anwser:

> A three-tier application is being created to host small news articles.
>   The application is expected to serve millions of users. When breaking
>   news occurs, the site must handle very large spikes in traffic without
>   significantly impacting database performance. Which design meets these
>   requirements while minimizing costs?

```
Options:
A.  Use auto scaling groups to increase the number of Amazon EC2 instances delivering the web application.
B.  Use auto scaling groups to increase the size of the Amazon RDS instances delivering the database
C.  Use Amazon DynamoDB strongly consistent reads to adjust for the increase in traffic
D.  Use DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) to cache read operations to the database
```

**Correct Answer:**

```
 D. Use DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) to cache read operations to the database
```

Though D is correct in the case the application is using DynamoDB as the backend database, however, **there is no indicator saying the underlying database is DynamoDB, here this answer is Incorrect.** Option A - though it increase cost, will be able to handle the need of large spikes which could cause database performance.

Am I missing anything here?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are studying for an AWS certification exam. You need to start by eliminating any possible answers that are invalid or obviously wrong, and then focus on the only options that are left.

A and C wouldn't help in this scenario. B is invalid because it says auto-scaling would increase the size of the RDS instances, but auto-scaling increases the number of instances, not the size. Thus by process of elimination D is the only possible answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out auto-scaling increases the number of instances, not the size.

Answer (score 0):

Auto scaling EC2 instances will result in more read / writes to your database, irregardless if its DynamoDB or RDS. This is because you're going to have literally more servers spinning up, serving more requests to your DB instances.

To answer your concern that the question doesn't specify the underlying database. You are missing the important, key concept of the question.

The question is asking how to scale without affecting your DB performance.

We can obviously rule #1 and #2 out, as spinning up more servers means more requests, and increasing your DB instance is going to cost a bit of money and affect performance.